# I don't know if I can still use the water

Tags: hadith, salat, fiqh, practical-islam, sharia

I want to wash a cloth that there is urine on it ,not sure though.the hand I used to put detergent on the urine part was also the same hand I used to pour water so I don't know if the urine has dropped inside the water
Can I use the water to rinse the cloth?

Answer (score 1):

As salaamu alaikum,

I hope that you are well.

Kindly find below a similar question and answer posted on a fiqh website >>>> :

"Impurity falling in a swimming pool

Q: If an impurity (e.g. urine, etc.) has to fall into a pool which holds 50 000 liters of water and is on a filter all the time (the water is flowing continuously), will the pool be considered naapaak?

A: If the pool is 5 metres by 5 metres (25 square metres) or larger in size, the water will not become impure. However, if the pool is smaller in size, the water will become impure. In this case, all the water will have to be removed and the pool will then be refilled with clean water.

And Allah Ta'ala (الله تعالى) knows best.

والغدير العظيم الذي لا يتحرك أحد طرفيه بتحريك الطرف الآخر إذا وقعت نجاسة في أحد جانبيه جاز الوضوء من الجانب الآخر لأن الظاهر أن النجاسة لا تصل إليه إذ أثر التحريك في السراية فوق أثر النجاسة ثم عن أبي حنيفة رحمه الله تعالى أنه يعتبر التحريك بالاغتسال وهو قول أبي يوسف رحمه الله تعالى وعنه التحريك باليد وعن محمد رحمه الله تعالى بالتوضي ووجه الأول أن الحاجة إلى الاغتسال في الحياض أشد منها إلى التوضي وبعضهم قدروا بالمساحة عشرا في عشر بذراع الكرباس توسعة للأمر على الناس وعليه الفتوى والمعتبر في العمق أن يكون بحال لا ينحسر بالاغتراف هو الصحيح وقوله في الكتاب جاز الوضوء من الجانب الآخر إشارة إلى أنه ينجس موضع الوقوع وعن أبي يوسف رحمه الله تعالى أنه لا ينجس إلا بظهور أثر النجاسة فيه كالماء الجاري (الهداية 1/21)

(و) أما (الماء الراكد إذا وقعت فيه نجاسة لا يجوز الوضوء به) لقوله - عليه الصلاة والسلام -: لا يبولن أحدكم في الماء الدائم ثم يتوضأ منه أو يشرب قال: (إلا أن يكون عشرة أذرع في عشرة أذرع) والأصل أن الماء القليل ينجس بوقوع النجاسة فيه والكثير لا، لقوله عليه الصلاة والسلام في البحر: هو الطهور ماؤه واعتبرناه فوجدناه ما لا يخلص بعضه إلى بعض. فنقول: كل ما لا يخلص بعضه إلى بعض لا ينجس بوقوع النجاسة فيه، وهذا معنى قولهم لا يتحرك أحد طرفيه بتحرك الطرف الآخر، وامتحن المشايخ الخلوص بالمساحة فوجدوه عشرا في عشر فقدروه بذلك تيسيرا (الاختيار لتعليل المختار 1/14)

لا يتوضأ بماء ساكن وقعت فيه نجاسة مطلقا سواء تغير أحد أوصافه أو لا ولم يبلغ الماء عشرة أذرع في عشرة (البحر الرائق (1/78"